# How to show custom page for 400 error in .net core 3.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, error-handling, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.0

I have my error handling setup in the following way:

Startup.cs

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseMiddleware<ExceptionHandlerMiddleware>();
    app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Error/Index");

    //I Added this as a test but it had no effect.
    app.Use((context, next) => {
        context.SetEndpoint(null);
        return next();
    });
    app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
    {
        OnPrepareResponse = (context) =>
        {
            context.Context.Response.GetTypedHeaders()
                .CacheControl = new CacheControlHeaderValue
            {
                MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromDays(30)
            };
        }
    });

    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
}
```

Now I tested this by trying something like localhost/mynotexistantpage and it works, I get my error page. Actually in most scenarios when I have tested this I got the error page. But there is one scenario where I don't get that page.

If you create a post action (any action really) and require a antiforgery token on it. Now if you submit a form to that method but in your html remove the antiforgery token that is automatically generated, the server responds with a 400 status and my error page is not used. The page that I get is one that the browser defaults to if you don't serve one.

An additional note: my exception handler did not even catch this error. The handler constructor looks something like this:

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
{
    try
    {
        await _requestDelegate.Invoke(context);
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        HandleExceptionAsync(context, exception);
    }
}
```

Why is this and how can I account for all scenarios when it comes to error handling?

Comment: You found a bug. I've just been looking into this and discovered that the problem is because the rexecute goes back to the same endpoint. It's because the endpoint to use was already selected and doesn't get cleared for a reexecute.

Comment: Here's the suggested workaround: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/13715#issuecomment-528929683.

Comment: @KirkLarkin I tried the workaround but that doesn't change anything on my end. I still get a 400 response and content on the page says: "This page isn’t working" which looks like its produced by the browser, it doesn't load my actual error page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was actually 2 problems. The first problem is a bug and a workaround can be found here:

https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/13715#issuecomment-528929683

The second problem was because I have auto validation on anti forgery token. This means that when page re-executes it is a post again and thus the anti-forgery fails again thus not being able to reach my error page. So the solution to that was to add IgnoreAntiforgeryToken attribute on the error controller.

Answer (score 0):

When antiforgery validation fails server (ASP.Net Core) returns error 404 and stops further processing of the request and none of your exception handlers will catch that error. What you can do is use `UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects` like below

```
app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Error"); // "/Error" is your custom error handling page.
```

And then do whatever you like to do with errors.

A full sample app [here](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore.Docs/tree/master/aspnetcore/fundamentals/error-handling/samples) for error handling using `UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute`.

Comment: But in my example above I already am using UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute and it has the behavior I described. Am I not understanding something?

Comment: Yes, if you goto [here](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore.Docs/blob/master/aspnetcore/fundamentals/error-handling/samples/2.x/ErrorHandlingSample/Pages/StatusCode.cshtml.cs). In `OnGet` you can redirect to another page (your custom error page) based on `ErrorStatusCode` or something else.

Comment: StatusCodeModel is a class you linked to. I assume I have to create one on my end for this to work. But how do I register my class in startup?

Comment: `StatusCodeModel` is a page. ASP.Net Core has Pages and traditional views with the controller.  You don't need to register anything. Just pass the URL path to the Page or View.

Comment: I'm sorry, I think I am now even more lost as to what you are trying to explain me. I think I need to start from the beginning to help us both get on same page. I already in my startup code call `app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Error");` However, when I get the error with antiforgery token, it does not redirect me to that url. So my error page that is meant to handle the error doesn't fire. So how in my code do I get .net core to redirect the user to the generic error page I already have existing?

Comment: @Bojan please check your project nuget and update if there are not on the latest version. Then try again. This scenario working for me.

Comment: I am updated to the latest version of .net core 3.0 and I still get a 400 response and content on the page says: "This page isn’t working" which looks like its produced by the browser, it doesn't load my actual error page.